# How to connect to Apache spark/hadoop from VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba, apache-spark, hadoop

I am familiar with SQL (especially postgres) and VBA, but on the Apache spark side, I am a total newbie, but it seems to run and return queries results much faster than using SQL?

As of now in my daily work, I connect my Excel VBA with Postgresql through `OLEDB` (others ppl use `ODBC` and etc.), so whenever I need to retrieve something from `DB`, I can easily do so by set a connection and write a SQL string in VBA, and then dump the output in the desired sheets and cells. But the drawback there is the speed, as my data grows larger and larger, when I need to run complicated `SQL queries` for complicated calculations or relations, it took a long long wait to get the results.

So other than upgrade our server which host the `DB`, I heard `Spark/Hadoop` is the solution for speeding up the task?

Typically when I need to do the VBA-postgres interaction, I do something like the following:

```
Public Sub refresh_cf()
    Dim dataConn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim strCON As String
    Dim strCmd As New ADODB.Command
    Dim loadTable As QueryTable

    strCON = "Server=server IP;" & _
             "DSN=PostgreSQL35W;" & _
             "UID=USERNAME;" & _
             "PWD=PASSWORD;" & _
             "Database=DBNAME;" & _
             "Port=5432;" & _
             "CommandTimeout=12"
    dataConn.ConnectionString = strCON
    dataConn.Open

    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE...."
    strCmd.ActiveConnection = dataConn
    strCmd.CommandType = adCmdText
    strCmd.CommandText = strSQL
    strCmd.CommandTimeout = 0

    Set loadTable = Sheet2.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=strCmd.Execute, 
    Destination:=Sheet2.Range("A4"))
    With loadTable
        .BackgroundQuery = False
        .AdjustColumnWidth = False
        .refresh
    End With       
End Sub
```

I am wondering if we can achieve the same to connect with Apache Spark or Hadoop and return query results by this way??

Say each of the databases we are processing is fairly huge, billions of rows (and countless cells per row), and if I perform some complex relational calculations within this DB, currently the postgres on our server may take hours if not days to complete the task (even the returned results might not be that big, i.e. does not exceed the 1.6 million rows limit of per excel sheet), is it worthy to utilize Hadoop or Spark via VBA if possible?

I know we can do this in `Python` for sure, something like:

**Python**

```
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext, Row
#or
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, Row
sc = SparkContext(...)
hiveCtx = HiveContext(sc)
#Then we can run query
hiveCtx.sql("""SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE....""")
```

Moreover, I find a [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hadoop/apache-hadoop-connect-excel-hive-odbc-driver) which introduced the ODBC connection to Hadoop, but can someone share your way if you are doing so, and provide some basic example code to clarify the process? Thanks.

Comment: If you are using VBA it is unlikely your data is that big to warrang that for consideration. Also, Spark is a processing engine, not a DB.

Comment: +1 to @thebluephantom.  A good rule of thumb is to use Big Data(like Hadoop) when you can no longer scale vertically.  Consider that you can reasonable buy/rent a server with 100s of GB of memory and TBs of disk space.  So if your database is smaller than this, moving to Hadoop/Spark is not worthwhile.

Comment: Say the DB we are processing is fairly huge, billions of rows (and countless cells per row), and if I perform some complex relational calculations within this DB, currently the postgres on our server may take tens of hours to complete the task (even the returned results might not be that big, i.e. does not exceed the 1.6 million rows limit of per excel sheet), and is Hadoop or Spark helpful under this kind of situation then if we can connect to it through vba?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Hadoop installed on my personal laptop, so I can't test this process, but I think it should be essentially like this.

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can see all details here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hadoop/apache-hadoop-connect-excel-hive-odbc-driver

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this is the same link as I mentioned in the last paragraph of my post, and essentially this connection is based on the GUI of excel... but I am looking for the string connection way in VBA (like the example I gave to connect the postgresql).